# Получить значение элемента массива в json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-encode

Сейчас у меня код вот такой, но он не работает (ошибка)

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://dictionary.yandex.net/api/v1/dicservice.json/lookup?key=dict.1.1.20180831T063038Z.89428291a5904b7b.53f166773e004d74002c2726ef4970f11ee5cd45&lang=ru-ru&ui=ru&text=привет");
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();

var o = JObject.Parse(json);

Console.WriteLine(o["def"]["pos"]);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Сам `json` загрузил вот сюда: [jsoneditoronline.org](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=340a9ec6a0c14323a371b7907355e890)

Нужно получить значение `pos`.

Comment: а что за ошибка? Пока ваш вопрос выглядит как спам!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://dictionary.yandex.net/api/v1/dicservice.json/lookup?key=dict.1.1.20180831T063038Z.89428291a5904b7b.53f166773e004d74002c2726ef4970f11ee5cd45&lang=ru-ru&ui=ru&text=привет");
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();

var o = JObject.Parse(json);

Console.WriteLine(o.SelectToken("def[0].pos").ToString());

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: а пояснить в чем проблема, можно?

Comment: спасибо, вот как это работает

Comment: @Monomax, что ты хочешь, чтобы я пояснил? Единственное отличие в коде - эта строка: `o.SelectToken("def[0].pos")`. И я не думаю, что нужно быть гением, что понять что тут происходит.

Comment: На всякий случай оставлю ссылку https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm